# Why does .skipWaiting() in my PWA take so long time?

Tags: firebase, progressive-web-apps

When I reload the web page shown in my PWA I can see a new version of the PWA is installed. The PWA service worker then waits for activation.

When I call `.skipWaiting()` the page reloads and the new version of the PWA is activated.

However it takes rather long time before the page starts to reload. I have no idea why, so some questions:

- What is going on there?
- Why does it take so long time?
- Are there some events that I could watch for in the service worker?
- How do I estimate the time it will take so I can tell the user?

I see this when I load the PWA from `localhost`, under `firebase serve`.

Comment: you would need to share some source code.
What does your 'install' event handler look like?

Comment: @ChrisLove Maybe, but I do not think it is that kind of problem, so to say. Not that simple kind of problem. I do not see the problem any more, but I am hesitating to say anything about the solution yet, since I am not sure why. (I saw the problem disappearing after cleaning the old cache at a surprising point in my code, but that may just be a coincidence. And since no one seems really interested I just forget it for now.)